# How to align a text below text to keep them in middle of div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

```css
#align_text_center{
 height:100%;
    display:flex;
}
#aligned_text_h1{
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="Container1">
        <div id="align_text_center">
            <h1 id="aligned_text_h1"></h1>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div id="Container2">
  <div id="align_text_center">
   <h1 id="aligned_text_h1"></h1>
  </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Welcome! I got again a bit problem while positioning the texts to it's position. I have a h1 element in the center of container1,container2 id's.
I want to align a second(and later a third) text below the first h1 element. I can't say it, so I made an interactive image about it. :(

Thank you for help! :)
[I draw an interactive image,click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULdnQ.png)

Comment: could you please add your tried code in fiddle...Thanks!

Comment: unclear question..what do u mean by i can't say it

Comment: Yes, code is better than an image. Also, *exactly how* is that image interactive?

Comment: Here you go,my interactive image is fine,please.

Answer (score 0):

Place all the elements you want to position in the same div, and then position that div, rather than positioning each element separately.